# Extract value's from XML to dataframe in R

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

I have multiple XML files in which I want to extract only certain parts from a certain level and store these values in a `data.frame`. The level is always called the same, namely "Invoice".

I want to extract the data from the level "Invoice". All the children of this level should be a row entity. For each row entity the `value`, `confidence` and `zone` should be extracted.

The only problem is that for each document the number of entities varies.

The `data.frame` should look like:

```
Doc. Nr.    Entity             Value         Zone               Confidence
doc1        OcrText            Text example  19 101 941 2625    76
doc1        InvoiceDate        17/06/2016    105 8 862 1555     100
doc1        InvoiceDate__day   17            105 8 862 1555     100
```

With the help of the packages `rvest` and `XML` I am able to extract the `zone`.

`read_xml(xmlfile) %>% xml_nodes("Invoice") %>% xml_nodes("zone") %>% xml_text()`

But I'm not able to extract the `value`, `confidence` and all the names of the children of the level "Invoice".

This is an example of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DOKuStar baseType="documentType" state="Ok" confidence="0" version="2.0">
  <Invoice baseType="documentType" state="Ok" confidence="0" producer="DOKuStar">
    <sources>
      <image guid=" fec8" />
    </sources>
    <OcrText baseType="fieldType" state="Reject" confidence="76">
      <value> Text example
      </value>
      <zone>19 101 941 2625</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </OcrText>
    <InvoiceDate baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="100" class="dateType">
      <value>17-06-2016
      </value>
      <zone>105 8 862 1555</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </InvoiceDate>
    <annotations>
      <annotation key="FileOutputPath">E:\..\Outgoing\</annotation>
    </annotations>
    <InvoiceDate__day baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="100">
      <value>17
      </value>
      <zone>105 8 862 1555</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </InvoiceDate__day>
    <InvoiceDate__month baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="100">
      <value>06
      </value>
      <zone>105 8 862 1555</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </InvoiceDate__month>
    <InvoiceDate__year baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="100">
      <value>2016
      </value>
      <zone>105 8 862 1555</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </InvoiceDate__year>
    <InvoiceNumber baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="100">
      <value>12365
      </value>
      <zone>105 80 862 1555</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </InvoiceNumber>
    <InvoiceTotalsTotalAmount baseType="fieldType" state="Ok" confidence="87">
      <value>21.98</value>
      <zone>595 2062 77 34</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </InvoiceTotalsTotalAmount>
    <InvoiceTotalsNetAmount baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </InvoiceTotalsNetAmount>
    <InvoiceTotalsVatAmount baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </InvoiceTotalsVatAmount>
    <InvoiceTotalsCurrency baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </InvoiceTotalsCurrency>
    <InvoiceTotals baseType="tableType" state="Ok" confidence="87">
      <value>21.98                  </value>
      <zone>595 2062 77 34</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
      <row baseType="tableRowType" state="Ok" confidence="0">
        <TotalAmount baseType="fieldType" state="Ok" confidence="100">
          <value>3.10</value>
          <zone>596 2029 63 30</zone>
          <sources>
            <image guid=" fec8" />
          </sources>
        </TotalAmount>
        <NetAmount baseType="fieldType" state="Ok" confidence="69">
          <value>2.56</value>
          <zone>287 2031 64 31</zone>
          <sources>
            <image guid=" fec8" />
          </sources>
        </NetAmount>
        <VatAmount baseType="fieldType" state="Ok" confidence="78">
          <value>0.54</value>
          <zone>444 2030 59 31</zone>
          <sources>
            <image guid=" fec8" />
          </sources>
        </VatAmount>
        <VatRate baseType="fieldType" state="Ok" confidence="83">
          <value>21.00</value>
          <zone>141 2035 30 26</zone>
          <sources>
            <image guid=" fec8" />
          </sources>
        </VatRate>
        <Currency baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
          <value>
          </value>
          <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
          <sources>
            <image guid=" fec8" />
          </sources>
        </Currency>
        <Type baseType="fieldType" state="Ok" confidence="0">
          <value>Vat</value>
        </Type>
      </row>
      <row baseType="tableRowType" state="Ok" confidence="0">
        <TotalAmount baseType="fieldType" state="Ok" confidence="56">
          <value>18.88</value>
          <zone>603 1993 73 33</zone>
          <sources>
            <image guid=" fec8" />
          </sources>
        </TotalAmount>
        <NetAmount baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
          <value>
          </value>
          <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
          <sources>
            <image guid=" fec8" />
          </sources>
        </NetAmount>
        <VatAmount baseType="fieldType" state="Ok" confidence="57">
          <value>2.99</value>
          <zone>653 1311 62 33</zone>
          <sources>
            <image guid=" fec8" />
          </sources>
        </VatAmount>
        <VatRate baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
          <value>
          </value>
          <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
          <sources>
            <image guid=" fec8" />
          </sources>
        </VatRate>
        <Currency baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
          <value>
          </value>
          <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
          <sources>
            <image guid=" fec8" />
          </sources>
        </Currency>
        <Type baseType="fieldType" state="Ok" confidence="0">
          <value>Vat</value>
        </Type>
      </row>
    </InvoiceTotals>
    <Address baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </Address>
    <Address__firstname baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </Address__firstname>
    <Address__lastname baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </Address__lastname>
    <Address__city baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </Address__city>
    <Address__cityline baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </Address__cityline>
    <Address__nameline baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </Address__nameline>
    <Address__streetline baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </Address__streetline>
    <Address__streetname baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </Address__streetname>
    <Address__streetnumber baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </Address__streetnumber>
    <Address__zipcode baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </Address__zipcode>
    <Postcode baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </Postcode>
    <BankAccountNumber baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>215 15 1 1</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </BankAccountNumber>
    <InvoiceAcceptgiroCode baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>215 15 1 1</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </InvoiceAcceptgiroCode>
    <Website baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </Website>
    <EmailAddress baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </EmailAddress>
    <BICCode baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>215 15 1 1</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </BICCode>
    <CoCNumber baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>215 15 1 1</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </CoCNumber>
    <DebtorNumber baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>215 15 1 1</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </DebtorNumber>
    <IBANCode baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </IBANCode>
    <IsCreditNote baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>105 8 862 1555</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </IsCreditNote>
    <IsKvKInvoice baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </IsKvKInvoice>
    <VATNumber baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>0 8 967 2974</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </VATNumber>
    <ScanFormAdministration baseType="fieldType" state="Empty" confidence="0">
      <value>
      </value>
      <zone>215 15 1 1</zone>
      <sources>
        <image guid=" fec8" />
      </sources>
    </ScanFormAdministration>
  </Invoice>
  <sourceInstances>
  </sourceInstances>
  <annotations>
  </annotations>
 </DOKuStar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another version, without any error checking:

```
library(rvest)
invoices<-read_xml("xmltext2.xml") %>% xml_nodes("Invoice")
children<-xml_children(invoices)

Entity<-xml_name(children)
Confidence<-xml_attr(children, "confidence")
df<-data.frame(Entity, Confidence)
df<-df[complete.cases(df),]
Value<-xml_find_all(children, "value") %>% xml_text()
Zone<-xml_find_all(children, "zone") %>% xml_text()
df<-cbind(df, Value, Zone)
df$Value<-trimws(df$Value)
```

This works well for the test provided about.  The stray nodes such as the source and annotations.  with a bit more work this can be extended to capture the invoice subtotals.

Answer (score 0):

Consider transforming your original XML with [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose declarative language used to transform XML files to various structures for end use needs. Once flattened and simplified, you can then read into R with the simple `xmlToDataFrame()`.

While R does not have a universal XSLT 1.0 processor in popular packages, R can leverage XSLT processors via other general purpose languages (Java, Python, PHP, VB), command-line interpreters (Bash, PowerShell), or dedicated installed XSLT processors (Xalan, Saxon) using `system()` calls:

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl and use in external calls/scripts of aforementioned programs)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="DOKuStar">
        <data>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Invoice/*" />
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Extracts all children of Invoice Element -->
    <xsl:template match="Invoice/*">
        <row>
            <doc.nr.>doc1</doc.nr.>
            <entity><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></entity>
            <value><xsl:apply-templates select="value"/></value>
            <zone><xsl:apply-templates select="zone"/></zone>
            <confidence><xsl:value-of select="@confidence"/></confidence>
        </row>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove multiple white space in value and zone text values -->
    <xsl:template match="value|zone">       
          <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>       
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML** Output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<data>
  <row>
    <doc.nr.>doc1</doc.nr.>
    <entity>sources</entity>
    <value/>
    <zone/>
    <confidence/>
  </row>
  <row>
    <doc.nr.>doc1</doc.nr.>
    <entity>OcrText</entity>
    <value>Text example</value>
    <zone>19 101 941 2625</zone>
    <confidence>76</confidence>
  </row>
  <row>
    <doc.nr.>doc1</doc.nr.>
    <entity>InvoiceDate</entity>
    <value>17-06-2016</value>
    <zone>105 8 862 1555</zone>
    <confidence>100</confidence>
  </row>
  <row>
    <doc.nr.>doc1</doc.nr.>
    <entity>annotations</entity>
    <value/>
    <zone/>
    <confidence/>
  </row>
...
```

**R** Script *(running a Python xslt transform script which outputs a file that R then reads in)*

```
library(XML)

system('python "C:\\Path\\To\\TransformScript.py"')
df <- xmlToDataFrame("C:\\Path\\To\\Output.xml", nodes = "row")

df

#    doc.nr.                   entity        value            zone confidence
# 1     doc1                  sources
# 2     doc1                  OcrText Text example 19 101 941 2625         76
# 3     doc1              InvoiceDate   17-06-2016  105 8 862 1555        100
# 4     doc1              annotations
# 5     doc1         InvoiceDate__day           17  105 8 862 1555        100
# 6     doc1       InvoiceDate__month           06  105 8 862 1555        100
# 7     doc1        InvoiceDate__year         2016  105 8 862 1555        100
# 8     doc1            InvoiceNumber        12365 105 80 862 1555        100
# 9     doc1 InvoiceTotalsTotalAmount        21.98  595 2062 77 34         87
# 10    doc1   InvoiceTotalsNetAmount                 0 8 967 2974          0
# 11    doc1   InvoiceTotalsVatAmount                 0 8 967 2974          0
# ...
```